# Regular Expression in Python: search() vs findall() for (\w)+

Tags: python, regex

I have created a regular expression as:

```
agentRegex = re.compile(r'Agent (\w)+')
```

And then I performed `search()` operation as:

```
agentRegex.search('Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.').group()
```

I obtained `'Agent Alice'` as output.

But when I performed `findall()` operation:

```
agentRegex.findall('Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.')
```

The output was `['e', 'l', 'e', 'b']`.

Shouldn't the output be `['Alice Agent', 'Agent Carol', 'Agent Eve', 'Agent Bob']`?

Comment: You want `(\w+)`, which is one group of many `\w`, not `(w)+`, which is many groups of one `\w` each.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall()` by default outputs a list of captured groups, in your case `(\w+)`.

Get rid of the captured group:

```
Agent \w+
```

**Example:**

```
>>> agentRegex = re.compile(r'Agent \w+')

>>> agentRegex.findall('Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.') 
['Agent Alice', 'Agent Carol', 'Agent Eve', 'Agent Bob']
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you elaborate why the output was `['e', 'l', 'e', 'b']` in case of findall() (the last letters of each names) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex:

```
'Agent (\w)+'
```

It will keep matching and capturing single `\w` characters after `'Agent '` and will keep overwriting the matched group with the next match. Thats how you get `['e', 'l', 'e', 'b']` which are the last characters of `['Alice', 'Carol', 'Eve', 'Bob']`

You got correct answer in `.search().group()` because `group()` defaults to `group(0)` which contains everything that got matched, but if you do `.search().group(1)` you will get `['e']`.

What you are looking for is capture the Agent as well as next word. So yo u can try like heemayl and Dietrich suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this too:

```
import re
agentRegex = re.compile(r'Agent\s+[^\s]+')
print agentRegex.findall('Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.') 
# ['Agent Alice', 'Agent Carol', 'Agent Eve', 'Agent Bob']
```

Comment: Yes @MYGz 15 but from OP's example it's not clear that he does not want `Agent 2345`.

Comment: You are right. Just dropping in a comment so that someone who is clueless can know the difference.

Comment: Actually, `Agent \w+` will also match `Agent 2345` as `\w` matches digits, too. `\S`=`[^\s]` matches any character other than whitespace, so `Agent\s+[^\s]+` will match `Agent    #@#%$%^&*()dgrtY&%^.??<`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew :D That must be an MI6 or FBI agent. Don't know why  we dont have a meta char for `[A-Za-z]`.